# Browse desktop files from iOS device over local network

Tags: ios, network-programming, filesystems, ios5, network-protocols

I currently have my app configured for file sharing through itunes.  However, I want to be able to browse through my my files located on my mac from my iOS device like the [FileBrowser app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/filebrowser-access-files-on/id364738545?mt=8) or the Files Connect app.  I know that these apps use a combination of the CIFS, SMB, AFP, FTP, SFTP, and WEBDAV protocols.  The [Tango](https://github.com/38leinaD/tango) c library looked promising for this but I could not get a good connection.  I have tried using Bonjour and the cocoahttpserver library but I don't think I need these to accomplish what I am trying to do.

I have been going around in circles on this one and I was wondering if anyone could help me out.  Any information would be helpful and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good tutorial for understanding Bonjour/Networking/Sockets/Streams. Not directly related to file sharing but a good place to start.

[Networking and Bonjour](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/)